# Oracle column number increase

Tags: sql, database, oracle10g

I would like to know how to increase the row number by 1 in Column 1 when Column 2 value changes in Oracle

What I am looking for is to achieve this :

```
 COL1   COL2    COL3 |
 1      2000    xx   |
 1       2000   xy   |
 1      2000    xyz  |
 2      3020    x    |
 2      3020    xiii |
 3      5666666   ueueu
```

Any idea ?

Comment: do you want to actually update col1 with these values?

Comment: yes @Sebas that s what i want to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for a window function:

```
select row_number() over (partition by col2 order by col3) as col1,
       col2, 
       col3
from the_table;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to increase `col1` value after updating `col2` on table `t_` then you can use trigger.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER upcol1
  AFTER UPDATE ON t_ FOR EACH ROW
  WHEN (old.col2 != new.col2)
BEGIN
  UPDATE t_ SET col1=:new.col1+1
    WHERE col2=:new.col2 AND col3=:new.col3;
END;
```